# How to render vertex only using geometry node?

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes

Expected: render what I see in the viewport.

Seen: Nothing in render.

I want to render vertext of a monkey. I simply converted a monkey to points than convert points to vertex. The vertex in the viewport is what I want, but when I render nothing is shown.

Not sure what I am missing here. I tried to set material but it does not work.

My file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/3pvGJqj4

[image]

[image]

Comment: Blender doesn't render vertices, it renders faces. If you only have vertices with no faces being drawn between them, there's nothing to render.
You can instanciate a small sphere on each vertex, wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: If you want to render what you see in the viewport, use a viewport render.  From 3D menu, view->viewport render image.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati It works. Would be great if your comment is converted to answer and I will accpet it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender doesn't render vertices, it renders faces. If you only have vertices with no faces being drawn between them, there's nothing to render.

But you could instanciate a small sphere on each vertex, then the sphere instances would show up in the render.